Am I using the StreamPlot function properly?
I want to examine the phase plot of the following dynamical system
\begin{align}\label{eq:x0_soliton_param}
    \dot{x}_0 &= \frac{2}{\mu}\sinh \mu \sin k - \frac{8}{\epsilon}\cosh\mu \sinh^{3}\mu\sin k \cos k\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(n-x_0)\cosh\mu(n-x_0)}{\cosh\mu(n+1-x_0)\cosh\mu(n-1-x_0)}\Big(1+\frac{\sinh^{2}\mu}{\cosh_0^{2}}\Big)\Big ( \frac{\sinh_0}{\cosh_2 \cosh_{-2}}\Big )
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \dot{k} &= -2\epsilon \sinh^{2}\mu (1+\sinh^{2}\mu)(1+\sin^{2}k)\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\tanh\mu(n-x_0)\cosh\mu(n-x_0)}{\cosh\mu(n+1-x_0)\cosh\mu(n-1-x_0)}\Big ( 1+\frac{\sinh^{2}\mu}{\cosh_0^{2}}\Big)\Big ( \frac{\cosh_0}{\cosh_2 \cosh_{-2}}\Big )
\end{align}
where $\mu = 3$ and $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2^{3}}$.
I utilize the StreamPlot function to do that.
\[Mu] = 3;
\[Epsilon] = 1/2^(1 + 2);
StreamPlot[{2/\[Mu] Sinh[\[Mu]] Sin[k] - 
   8/\[Epsilon] Cosh[\[Mu]] (Sinh[\[Mu]])^3 Sin[k] Cos[
     k] Sum[((n - x) Cosh[\[Mu] (n - x)])/(
      Cosh[\[Mu] (n + 1 - x)] Cosh[\[Mu] (n - 1 - 
           x)]) (1 + (Sinh[\[Mu]])^2/(Cosh[\[Mu] (n - 
             x)])^2) (Sinh[\[Mu] (n - x)]/(
       Cosh[\[Mu] (n + 2 - x)] Cosh[\[Mu] (n - 2 - x)])), {n, -50, 
      50}], -2 \[Epsilon] (Sinh[\[Mu]])^2 (1 + (Sinh[\[Mu]])^2) (1 + \
(Sin[k])^2) Sum[(Tanh[\[Mu] (n - x)] Cosh[\[Mu] (n - x)])/(
     Cosh[\[Mu] (n + 1 - x)] Cosh[\[Mu] (n - 1 - 
          x)]) (1 + (Sinh[\[Mu]])^2/(Cosh[\[Mu] (n - 
            x)])^2) (Cosh[\[Mu] (n - x)]/(
      Cosh[\[Mu] (n + 2 - x)] Cosh[\[Mu] (n - 2 - x)])), {n, -50, 
     50}]}, {x, -1, 1},{k, 0, 0.1}]

However, what I see is not what I expect and so I suspect I am utilizing the function incorrectly. For $\mu=3$, I expected to see homoclinic orbits, but what I see is:


Looks like a job for @Rahul's myStreamPlot (updated here), which generates

Still not beautiful and I don't see any heteroclinic orbits, but at least there's more than one arrow!

Changing the sum truncation to ${n,-1,1}$ and ${h,-1,1}$ yields such an orbit. It seems that the parameter regime for the variable $k$ in which this orbits occur is very small.
